# Limit IE8 to a single window (always use tabs)

Tags: windows-7, windows, internet-explorer-8, browser-tabs

How can I prevent Internet Explorer 8 from opening multiple windows? I only want a single IE window, with multiple tabs.

Sometimes a have multiple browser windows open and I don't like it when I have to choose which one I want to open in the Windows 7 taskbar.

Answer (score 3):

Go to **Internet Options** > **General**. Click on the "**Settings**" button for Tabs.

Set the following

- When a pop-up is encountered: **Always open pop-ups in a new tab**.
- Open links from other programs in: **A new tab in the current window**.