# IE9: How to open Links in new tab, not in a new window?

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

I have an intranet page with two links that have a target="_blank" option. One of the opens in a new window, the other in a new tab. Why is there a difference? What can I do to open both links in a new tab?

Comment: Check this SO answer, it could help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/17695599/763747

Answer (score 1):

It depends on browser implementation. `target="_blank"` does not specify whether the link
open in new tab or new window.

To always open in new tab:

Right click on the link, Open In New Tab

OR

Middle-click on the link

OR

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> key, Tools, Internet Options, General. Click on the "Settings" button in "Tabs" section.

Choose those options:

```
When a pop-up is encountered: Always open pop-ups in a new tab.

Open links from other programs in: A new tab in the current window.
```

Ref: [Limit IE8 to a single window (always use tabs)](https://superuser.com/questions/139020/limit-ie8-to-a-single-window-always-use-tabs)

Comment: That's what I already know. But is there a option to tell IE to not open a new window but a new tab?

Comment: Does last method works?

Comment: No, it doesn't. But I found out it has something to do with in what zone (local intranet, trusted sites) the target is. I'm further investigating this issue